# Posting on Facebook page using Koala with automatic renewal of auth code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using Rails 4 and have a working system to post on three different Facebook-PAGES using Koala. The only problem is that I have the Koala API auth codes hard coded into initializers and I need to renew them every 60 days (sometimes earlier). I have read, and re-read, every SO-question as well as the documentation but get none the wiser.

I do NOT have any users logging into the website through Facebook or anything like that. This is all handled as a rake, posting excerpts of my blog posts on my Facebook-page.

I have the following information (all tokens, ID's etc are examples):

```
- My application ID: my_app_id #=> 12343423423749274734
- My application secret: my_app_secret #=> fc2323cdf2ce2312cdc121efed212
- Page id for first Facebook Page (of three): fb_page1_id #=> 343395105021155
```

With this I can create a Koala-Oauth connection:

```
oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(my_app_id, my_app_secret, "http://www.mywebsite.com")
```

by which I can get an app_access_token:

```
oauth.get_app_access_token #=> 1231231726347364273|VhfeSDf43JdsdfJsERFE
```

This is, however, a dead end to me. I can't use this for anything.

If I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer I can get an access token for my application that looks something like this:

```
tmp_token = "EAADaSDASDAMZBoBEBADBDuAqvgUYJPe7sJ5qmgoF3N1awXR4VTET3FYzXFZAPz0jLAoo8d4aaASd9BBZAp9aWbHB2xEvjFbo5At8ekuwyhFDCKbP0m4OYWmbM9GjSfq2KibjASDASDGAAHZCLIVmjWf2JQwj0N0VWBytI2eiswZDZD"
```

by which I can create the rest:

```
base_connection = Koala::Facebook::API.new(tmp_token)
page_1_token = base_connection.get_page_access_token(fb_page1_id)
page_1_api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page_1_token)
page_1_api.put_connections("me", "feed", message: "Test")
```

...which successfully posts "Test" to my Facebook Page.

The problems I have now are:

- I need to manually renew the `tmp_token` in my initializer every 30-60 days, which is the problem I need to get away from.
- I don't understand how to get from the `oauth.get_app_access_token` to `tmp_token`. Basically, I can't create a `tmp_token` automatically in my rake-function.

I realize it could have to do with using:

```
oauth.url_for_oauth_code
```

to get the `code` variable as a GET and then use

```
oauth.get_access_token(code)
```

Is this the right (only?) way to go?

I tried the code I got in my adress field and input it into `oauth.get_access_token(code)` in my console but got an error: "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request [HTTP 400]" when I did that.

So, now I am very confused how to proceed.

How can I make this **fully automated with no manual intervention** so that I either:

- renew my tmp_token automatically on a frequent basis so I don't end up with expired a token?
- OR, create a tmp_token in my rake-function?

Comment: You can not renew user tokens without user interaction; page access tokens however can be extended to have no default expiry at all.

Comment: CBroe: So, are you saying that the 'page_1_token' in my example above can be set to have no expiry? How would I do that, in that case? Any way of solving this problem is fine with me, as long as it is solved.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks. I will re-read that. Do you know, by any chance, how to see the expiry date of a token?

Comment: See sub-chapter about debugging tokens ...

Comment: The problem I have is that everything is a bit "over my head" so to speak. I am having a hard time transferring the information there to ruby-code I can actually use.

Comment: You don’t need to do any coding if you just want to debug a specific token once, that’s what the debug tool is for.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it pretty much all solved except for one crucial point. How do I get the first temporary/short lived token automatically? I.e. without having to manually go to the Facebook Tool Explorer page. I am trying to find how to use Koala for it but can only find how to exchange one, not create the first one.

Comment: You can not get a user access token without user interaction; you need to implement the login flow to get one.

Comment: Considering that fact, I have instead "solved" this by adding a checker to see if the token has expired. If it has, an email is posted to me reminding me to update the token. I can't believe there is no better way to handle this.

Comment: There is - which brings us back to the very first comment.

Comment: You mean the page_access_tokens? I have not been able to figure out how to use those to post to my Facebook-page though.